# Application path in Weblogic server

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, struts, contextpath

In Struts action class how do I get the application path?

I want to read an XML file from *webcontent*\applicationName\Config\myxml.xml

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise against keeping the file in that location because then it can be easily accessed publicly using `http://yourURl/applicationContext/Config/myxml.xml` for example. I think you should move it under the `WEB-INF` folder.

You should be able to do something like below (quick code on the fly don't hold me to it):-

```
public ActionForward foo(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response){
    ServletContext context = request.getSession().getServletConext();
    InputStream stream = context.getResourceAsStream("Config/myxml.xml");
    if(stream!=null){
         //load your XML file from the stream
    }
}
```

If you are using struts2 then you can access the ServletContext using [ServletActionContext](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.2/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/ServletActionContext.html) as well:-

```
ServletContext context = ServletActionContext.getServletContext();
```